# NSMutableDictionary that retains its keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, core-foundation

I'm trying to figure out how to create an NSMutableDictionary that retains instead of copies its keys. I have implemented -(NSUInteger)hash and -(id)isEqual: for my desired keys, I am just having trouble figuring out which options to specify in the callbacks.

```
CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks    keyCallbacks    = { 0, NULL, NULL, CFCopyDescription, CFEqual, NULL };


self.commonParents = (NSMutableDictionary*)CFBridgingRelease(CFDictionaryCreateMutable(nil, 0, &keyCallbacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks));
```

The above code works correctly in ARC for using weak references to keys, but what if I want strong references? What should the key callbacks look like?

Comment: Why do you feel there is a need to change how a dictionary deals with its keys? Why does your code depend of the keys being retained instead of copied? There may be a better solution if we knew why you wanted this.

Comment: I second rmaddy's question. Also, if you use a non-standard dictionary, `CFDictionary` is no longer safe to cast to `NSMutableDictionary*`. Toll-free bridging between those types implicitly relies on the `CFDictionary` using the standard `CFType` callbacks. Finally, have you looked at `NSMapTable`?

Comment: I've come across enough situations where I've wanted slightly different memory management semantics around an `NSDictionary` that this doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: @Dave Except that the next programmer who needs to maintain the code will be: WTF? There needs to be a really compelling reason.

Comment: my keys are a special object that contain a uniqueID, as well as various other data that could potentially be changed over the lifetime of the object. It would be a lot easier to be able to key the dictionary by these objects instead of having to manually generate a unique key just to use for the same purpose every time

Comment: Perhaps the better solution is to write your own collection class or subclass `NSDictionary`. From the Apple docs: "... a key can be any object (provided that it conforms to the NSCopying protocol ..."

Comment: Ok I tried and implemented `NSMapTable` and it does accomplish what I want. It's just a shame that I won't be able to support < iOS 6.0 because of the limitations of NSDictionary. There must be a way to customize the behavior for keys using `CFDictionaryMutableCreate`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr:

Create a `CFDictionaryRef` with the provided default callback functions.  It'll do what you want.  Just don't call it an `NSDictionary`.

---

Yes, you can create a `CFDictionaryRef` that retains its keys and does not copy them.  This is, in fact, the *default behavior* of a `CFDictionaryRef`.

The documentation for `CFDictionaryCreateMutable()` says:

> If the dictionary will contain only CFType objects, then pass a pointer to `kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks` as this parameter to use the default callback functions.

(So if you're only going to be putting normal Objective-C objects into the array and not random things like `void *` pointers or whatever, this is what you want)

And the documentation for `kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks` says:

> Predefined `CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks` structure containing a set of callbacks appropriate for use when the keys of a CFDictionary are all CFType-derived objects.
>   The retain callback is `CFRetain`, the release callback is `CFRelease`, the copy callback is `CFCopyDescription`, the equal callback is `CFEqual`. Therefore, if you use a pointer to this constant when creating the dictionary, keys are automatically retained when added to the collection, and released when removed from the collection.

Note that the `retain` callback is [`CFRetain()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001203-CH201-F11072) and not something like `CFCopyObject` (which doesn't actually exist).

In fact, Core Foundation doesn't have a canonical way to "copy any object", which is why functions like `CFStringCreateCopy`, `CFArrayCreateCopy`, `CGPathCreateCopy`, etc exist.

So, what you can do is create your dictionary like this:

```
CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
```

And you now have a dictionary that retains its keys and does not copy them.

I'm going to put the following bit in big letters so that you grok what I'm about to say:

## This dictionary you've created is not an `NSDictionary`.

Yes, `NSDictionary` and `CFDictionaryRef` are toll-free bridged.  But casting this `CFDictionaryRef` to an `NSDictionary` would be an abuse of that bridging, because of this line in the `NSDictionary` documentation:

> ...a key can be any object (provided that it conforms to the `NSCopying` protocol—see below)

Similarly, the documentation for `-[NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey:]` explicitly says:

> The key is copied (using `copyWithZone:`; keys must conform to the NSCopying protocol).

The keys in your dictionary don't have to conform to `<NSCopying>` and are not copied using `-copyWithZone:`, which means your dictionary is NOT an `NSDictionary` (or `NSMutableDictionary`).  Any time you see `NSDictionary` used in code, you should be providing a key-value map where the keys are *copied* (not retained).  That is the API contract.  To do anything else could result in undefined behavior.

(The fact that some objects override `-copy` to `return [self retain]` is an implementation detail and is not relevant to this discussion on "what is an `NSDictionary`".)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer is buried in comment, so I'll highlight it here:  The simplest approach is to use a `+[NSMapTable strongToStrongObjectsMapTable]` (or maybe one of the variants with `weak` references).

Answer (score 0):

My suggest is that instead of doing this you subclass NSString or whatever class you're using as key, and override the copy method in a way that it returns the string retained, instead of a copied string.

Comment: This is going to cause all kinds of issues for other code that actually wants of copy of instances of the class.

Comment: I've seen this as a possible solution but my fear is that is will have wider ramifications as it's generally not a great idea to do things like this. Shouldn't the KeyCallbacks work if specified correctly?

Comment: This is an appropriate solution if the object is immutable.  For example, `-[NSString copy]` is essentially just `return [self retain]`, but `-[NSString mutableCopy]` does a full-on copy.  If the object is mutable, however, then the `copy` method should return a copy.

Comment: My object has various properties and is mutable. The hash of the object, however, is immutable and will stay the same regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is 2 possibles solutions that could be achieved using plain old NSMutableDictionary. They are not as elegant as NSMapTable would be.
You state that each of your Key have a `uniqueID`, so I assume that this Value won't change over time.

**Option 1** :
Use the `uniqueID` of your actual key to be the key of an NSMutableDictionary that would store NSArray of `@[key, value]` so the whole structure look like this
`@{ key1.uniqueID : @[key1, value1], key2.uniqueID : @[key2 : value2] }`

**Option 2** :
Make a subclass of NSObject that is a wrapper around option 1. Or any variation on option 1.

Those are only valid if `uniqueID` never change